# How to take this derivative? A question concerning a paper from Holley Stroock 1976

Tags: markov-process

In the page 199 of  the paper [A Martingale approach to Infinite Systems of Interacting Processes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176996130) one reads:

[image]

I suspect that (1.5) is incorrect

To simplify notation, let's  write $X_\theta^s(t) = \exp(F(\lambda))$
where 
$$F(\lambda) = \int_s^{s\vee t} \lambda\theta(u) d\tilde\alpha(u) - \sum_k \int_s^{t\vee s} c_k(u) (e^{-2\lambda\theta_k(u)\alpha_k(u)} - 1 + 2 \lambda\theta_k(u) \alpha_k(u))\, du $$

Now taking the derivative yields:
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda} X_\theta^s(t) = \exp(F(\lambda))F'(\lambda)\\ 
\frac{d^2}{(d\lambda)^2} X_\theta^s(t) = \exp(F(\lambda))(F'(\lambda))^2 + \exp(F(\lambda))F''(\lambda) \\  $$

Every object here is also a martingale. We note that $F(0) = 0$ so the exponential terms vanish. Now we need to compute $F'$ and $F''$
$$ F'(\lambda) =  \int_s^{s\vee t} \theta(u) d\tilde\alpha(u) \\- \sum_k \int_s^{t\vee s} c_k(u) \big((-2\theta_k(u)\alpha_k(u))e^{-2\lambda\theta_k(u)\alpha_k(u)}  + 2 \theta_k(u) \alpha_k(u)\big)\, du$$
$$ F''(\lambda) = - \sum_k \int_s^{t\vee s} c_k(u) ((4\theta^2_k(u)\alpha^2_k(u))e^{-2\lambda\theta_k(u)\alpha_k(u)}  )\, du$$

So
$$F'(0) = \int_s^{s\vee t} \theta(u) d\tilde\alpha(u)  $$
and

$$  F''(0) = - 4 \sum_k \int_s^{t\vee s} c_k(u) \theta^2_k(u)\alpha^2_k(u) \, du$$

So $|\theta(u)|_{c(u)}^2 $ should be

$$|\theta(u)|_{c(u)}^2  = \sum_k c_k(u) \alpha^2_k(u)\theta^2_k(u) $$

Therefore (1.5) is incorrect,

and for a better notation we should write
$$|\theta(u)|_{c(u),\alpha(u)}^2  = \sum_k c_k(u) \alpha^2_k(u)\theta^2_k(u)$$ 
 Or am I missing something?